# Express js with mysql update only fields that are passed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I've been trying to setup a rest API for a few days now.  I've been following a great tutorial that really helped me understand a large part of how these work (sending requests, getting responses, etc).  However it uses MongoDB and Mongoose.  I'm using MySQL.  My tables and views are a bit complicated so I decided instead of using an ORM I'd just use mysql2 package and do the querying myself.  I'm stuck with trying to `PATCH` and `PUT` at the moment.  Part of my front end functions by sometimes only sending 1 or 2 fields that need to be updatd (a `PATCH` from everything I've gathered).  So I used part of the MongoDB and Mongoose tutorial to build an array of objects and pass them into `connection.query`. Here's my patch route:

```
router.patch('/:txnid', (req, res, next) => { //UPDATE fields that are passed
    const txnid = req.params.txnid;

     for (const field of req.body) {
         fieldsToUpdate[field.name] = field.value;
     }

    connection.query("UPDATE QuoteToClose SET ? WHERE qb_TxnID = '" + txnid + "'", { fieldsToUpdate }, function (error, results) {
        if (error) {
            res.status(404).json({
                message: error,
                field: fieldsToUpdate
            });
        } else {
            res.status(201).json({
                "record_count" : results.length,
                "error": null,
                "response": results
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Sometimes I will pass 1 field, sometimes I will pass 2.  In this case I'm only passing 1. I build my body in POSTMAN and send this with the PATCH request:

```
[
    {
    "name": "margin",
    "value": "50"
    }
]
```

When I run this through POSTMAN I get the error:

```
{
    "message": {
        "code": "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR",
        "errno": 1054,
        "sqlState": "42S22",
        "sqlMessage": "Unknown column 'fieldsToUpdate' in 'field list'"
    },
    "field": {
        "margin": "50"
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why though.  I'm not using Mongoose unfortunately so I don't know if something is dependent on it that I'm missing.  My body parser is set like this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

I want to dynamically build that query instead of specifying each field (it just seems cleaner this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fieldsToUpdate is already an object. If you remove the curlies when you parameterize if you should be good to go:

```
connection.query("UPDATE QuoteToClose SET ? WHERE qb_TxnID = '" + txnid + "'", fieldsToUpdate,
```

Also, as a side note that string concatenation is a bad idea, you're just asking for a SQL Injection attack.

Comment: So I should use Sequelize then, huh?  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @drpcken I'm not saying you should use Sequelize, I'm just saying that you should parameterize all your inputs and sanitize them rather than using string concatenation.  Sequelize is useful but not a requirement.

Comment: Ahh I see what you mean now.  I remember reading that using ? as placeholders did that for you.  Do you mean that using `connection.query("UPDATE QuoteToClose SET ? WHERE qb_TxnID = ?", [fieldsToUpdate, txnid], function (error, results) {` would be safer?

Comment: I did mean to parameterize the transaction id field, but you'll have to check the docs on whichever MySQL-node module you're using to validate the syntax.  Not all of them accept SET fields to be parameterized iirc and there may be some need to merge the fieldsToUpdate with it, not sure.

Answer (score 3):

Hi im using this library build dynamic queries.https://www.npmjs.com/package/flexqp

```
let result = await qp.executeUpdatePromise('update user set ?  where user.id = ?', [user, user.id], dbconfig);
```

user  is an object with lots of sub elements, the library will auto populate the

query to E.g update user set name = 'xxx' , address ='xxx' ..etc where user.id = 1

Comment: Thankyou so much, it is  the best solution "flexqp"